# trigger fancy box from div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have seen several different variations to this questions but non seem to help.  I simply want to trigger fancybox from a div. I have a div:

```
<div class="port web">Website</div>
```

This div has certain css feature to it:

```
  .web{
    font-size: 80px;
    color: rgba(255,0,0,.8);
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
}
```

I am looking for a way to click .web to open up a fancy box.  I am an amateur to i tried to place the div into the fancybox anchor, which i see was a rookie mistake.  I have some knowledge of jquery if that help. Thanks.

```
 <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="image/bg.jpg"><div class="port web">Website</div><img src="small_image_1.jpg" alt=""></a>



 $(document) .ready(function(){

         $('.web').animate({left:'12.5em', top:'6.5em'}, 3500);
    });
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. It that not working for you?

Comment: @yuvalsab Yea it works but not when jquery is added onto the div.  I will update it with the jquery

Comment: @yuvalsab i just added the script to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add `fancybox` class and `href` to your div element:

```
<div class="fancybox port web" href="image/bg.jpg">Website</div>
```

It does not matter if your trigger element is anchor or div, or whatever. If you would use v3, then you could just add `data-fancybox` and `data-src` attributes and it would just work without writing a single JS line.

Comment: I worked! However the there is no indicator to click the link because when is hovers doesnt show the point finger

Comment: appreciate the help